# Fusioncharts Scatter anchors

Tags: php, html

Is there a way for me to change the anchors in Fusioncharts to be an image of my own? ideally i would enter a png name so it could overlay the map.  i know you can control other items (color, size on Z axis etc) and I have the scatter chart working already, just need to know how to add a custom icon/graphic to my anchors.

Thanks,
Silver Tiger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionCharts XT does not support images to be used as Anchors in the Scatter Chart.

For more information on 'Scatter (XY Plot) Chart Specification Sheet', please refer to the [link](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/chart-guide/select-scatter-chart/creating-a-select-scatter-chart.html),

Comment: yeah .. i'm going to have to either hack the source to add my own anchors or find an alternative custom JS/PHP/CSS solution. great charts .. but I need this one :)